# How to generate event codes in the conversion of XML to EXI?

Tags: xml, exi

Can anyone explain how to generate event codes for XML to EXI Conversion?

Example XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<notebook date="2007-09-12">
 <note category="EXI" date="2007-07-23">
  <subject>EXI</subject>
  <body>Do not forget it!</body>
 </note>
 <note date="2007-09-12">
  <subject>Shopping List</subject>
  <body>milk, honey</body>
 </note>
</notebook>
```

I have gone through with the below url but unable to understand.

https://www.w3.org/TR/exi/#grammarEventCodes

Please help me out in this...

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal answer for your question.

It highly depends on what schema information (XSDs) is to be used etc.

I suggest you to take a look at the [EXI Primer](https://www.w3.org/TR/exi-primer/) which walks you through the example without a schema and with schema information.